# how can I make recommendation model using python's scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I'm learning statistical learning these days using python's pandas and scikit-learn library and they're fantastic tools for me.

I could have learned the way of classification, regression and also clustering with them of course.

But, I cannot find the way how can I start with them when I would like to make a recommendation model. For example, if I have a customer's purchase dataset, which contains date, product name, product maker, price, order device etc...

What is the problem type of recommendation? classification, regression, or anything else?

In fact, I could find out there are very famous algorithms like collaborative filtering when someone has to solve this problem.

If so, can I use those algorithms using scikit-learn? or should I have to learn another M.L libraries?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Scikit-learn does not offer any recommendation system tools. You can give a look at [mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) which is giving really easy to start proposition or [spark](http://spark.apache.org/mllib/).

However recommendation is a problem in itself in machine learning word. It can be regression if you are trying to predict the rate that a user would give to a movie for instance or classification if you want to know if a user will like the movie or not (binary choice). 
The important thing is that recommendation is using tools and algorithms dedicated to this problem like item-based or content-based recommendation. These concepts are actually quite simple to understand and implementing yourself a little recommendation engine might be the best.

I advice you the book [*mahout in action*](https://www.manning.com/books/mahout-in-action) which is a great introduction to recommendation concept

Comment: thank you so much. in fact, I just wanted to use sklearn and pandas combination because of easy to use if there is a way and of couse I guessed there may be absolutely a good solution based of them. but, after a few days of googling I could not find anyway and I already started to learn spark framework for this agenda.

Comment: You can keep pandas in your toolbox for recommender but scikit learn does not bring algorithm dedicated.

Comment: ok, I got it. in fact, I built it using spark framework as for recommendation, but I also used pandas when data cleansing and aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

How about Crab https://github.com/python-recsys/crab, which is a a Python framework for building recommender engines integrated with the world of scientific Python packages (numpy, scipy, matplotlib).

I have not used this framework but just found it. And it seems there is only version 0.1 and Crab hasn't been updated for years. So I doubt whether it is well documented. Whatever, if you decide to try Crab, please give us a feedback after that:)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this really answers the question. OP wants to know what type of algorithm they should use. I think it's better if they develop a better understanding of their problem, before adding more tools.